# Rattle does not run as normal user but runs as root in a HPC cluster

Tags: hpc, gtk2, rattle

Rattle opens/runs when run as root user and throws up gtk2 error when run as normal user with sudo permission. Can anyone help as I am a novice in rattle.

The secnario is a HPC setup. On the master node having GUI, I am able to atleast run rattle on as root user. However on compute node(RHEL7.4-Comptute node) I am unable to run a even root. can we install R/rattle on a non GUI RHEL?

I have shared the details of running rattle as root and normal user. Please let me know if any further details need to be collected

root@mgt1

> library("rattle")
>   Rattle: A free graphical interface for data science with R.
>   Version 5.3.0 Copyright (c) 2006-2018 Togaware Pty Ltd.
>   Type 'rattle()' to shake, rattle, and roll your data.
>   rattle()
>   Loading required package: RGtk2

(and rattle GUI page opens)

```
> .libPaths()
```

[1] "/usr/lib64/R/library" "/usr/share/R/library"

> system.file(package="rattle")

[1] "/usr/lib64/R/library/rattle"

```
hpcuser@mgt1 (home directory: /nfsshare/home/hpcuser/)
```

> library("rattle")
>   Rattle: A free graphical interface for data science with R.
>   Version 5.3.0 Copyright (c) 2006-2018 Togaware Pty Ltd.
>   Type 'rattle()' to shake, rattle, and roll your data.
>   rattle()
>   Error in rattle() :
>   The RGtk2 package is not available but is required.
>   Please install the package using, for example:

install.packages("RGtk2")

```
> .libPaths()
```

[1] "/nfsshare/home/hpcuser/anaconda3/lib/R/library"

```
> system.file(package="rattle")
```

[1] "/nfsshare/home/hpcuser/anaconda3/lib/R/library/rattle"

Answer (score 0):

When you fire up rattle() it opens a GTK based graphical user interface. The compute nodes (often by definition) have no where to display to unless you set up your X DISPLAY to redirect to the master node which has a display.

As to why it runs as root but not as a normal user, that is odd. I suspect gtk2 libraries may have been installed with wrong permissions? As a normal user can you see /usr/lib64/R/library and /usr/share/R/library?